# ImageMagick and transparent background for animated gif

Tags: imagemagick

I have an animation as a batch of .png files (100 files). The background is transparent in the source .png files. I want to convert them into a single animated gif. I have tried this command:

```
convert -delay 0 -loop 0 -alpha set *.png ani.gif
```

But the result is the following (green is the HTML page background):

[image]

How should I remove the previous frames from an every following one?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I've found `-dispose previous`.

**UPDATE**

OK, `convert -delay 0 -loop 0 -alpha set -dispose previous *.png ani.gif`

Comment: If you still face transparency issue you should set  `-dispose background` . More info: https://superuser.com/questions/555490/transparency-issues-when-converting-pngs-to-gif

Answer (score 23):

The solution is here:

http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2601

The magic keyword seems to be “dispose” and calling the following fixed the problem:

```
convert -dispose 2 screencapture-*.tga screencapture.gif
```

Comment: Using `-dispose previous` almost worked, with the first image never going away.  I found that using `-dispose 2` worked.